# Need to hide button until quiz is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, content-management-system, show-hide

I am needing to hide the button at the bottom that says "chapter two" until the quiz above is submitted. There is already a class being added when the quiz is submitted that is called "qmn_results_page"

So, ideally, I can write something that would say when "qmn_results_page" is on the page, show "quiz_button"

Is this a thing? Javascript is not my forte!

Here is the link: http://adventuretoward.com/client/kids247/chapter-one-questions/

Comment: Please post code in the body of your post so we can help you.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that since it's dynamic & the class is added as you complete the quiz?

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to help you if you don't provide at least some kind of code relating to the website. The best I could do is give general advice. If the quiz is being submitted through a button click you can bind the event for showing "Chapter 2" with that button click. But I have no idea how the quiz is being submitted and you won't get any specific advice if we can't see what the code is currently doing.

Comment: Shooting in the dark. document.querySelector(".quiz_button").style.display = "none"; ?
 
DEMO: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FR7OVVREKKTI

Or possibly this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FR7PA0P2A941

This code will only work if the classes (qmn_results_page & quiz_button) are used once on the page, if they are used more than once then you will need to run a loop and use `.querySelectorAll`

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add a script that checks if the results page is showing by searching for an element with `qmn_results_page` as a class (which is an indicator that the user has completed the test and is on the answer review page). If it is present, then change the style of the button of class `quiz_button` to `block` so that it is no longer hidden.

The fancy `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { ... });` wrapper I included below basically tells the page to run this code each time the page is loaded (and when the form is submitted).

Please add this script to your chapter-one-questions page and let me know if it helps:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        if (document.querySelector('.qmn_results_page') != null) 
            document.querySelector('.quiz_button').style.display = 'block';
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The button is not hidden by default. If she has access to the css of the page then she could change `.quiz_button` to `display: none;` by default but if not then all your code does is show a button that is already visible.

Comment: I realize that from her wording "*I am needing to hide the button at the bottom that says "chapter two" until the quiz above is submitted*" it may sound that way, but I registered on her site and looked at the issue specifically. Currently, it is always hidden, and she wants it to appear after the form is successfully filled out and submitted.

Comment: For example, log into her site using my credentials: `user: tester123
pass: 5I0Y0WHNV19GG(UK`, fill out the form, and click submit. At the bottom of the page there is no "Chapter Two" button.

Comment: Ah so to a user who is not registered they can view the button. I didn't take the time to register *Edit: I reloaded the page and I notice the code has changed since I last viewed it and the button is not visible at all on load for registered or visiting users.* In that case I'm upvoting the answer since it seems to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you. I think the question could certainly have benefited from some test login credentials. I was bored and this one wasn't getting much attention so I figured "why not sign up" haha